# PGSQL - inserting null values into table

Tags: postgresql, insert, null

After executing the following query:

```
insert into regiony 
(m_valid, m_validationreport, 
m_creation_timestamp, m_creation_user, 
m_modification_timestamp, m_modification_user, 
instance, kod_regionu, nazwa_gminy, kod_teryt) 

select distinct NULL, NULL, now(), 'abc', now(), 
'abc', NULL, region_poch, export_gmina, replace(teryt, '|', '') from source_table
```

I get the following error:

ERROR: column "m_valid" is of type boolean but expression is of type text

I tried to convert the null value to boolean (NULL::boolean), and it worked for boolean, but the instance column in target table (regiony) is of type XML and PGSQL refuses to convert NULL to XML. After converting null to xml, I get:

ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type xml

any suggestions? All of the columns receiving null values allow null values and I'm running out of ideas.

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: Could you show the structure of the table?

Comment: Using `distinct` with NULLs seems rather dubious.

Comment: `select null::xml` works fine in 9.2. (`select ''::xml` is still broken, though, so beware if you've default values or something to that effect.)

Comment: sure, what exactly do you want to see? just columns + datatypes or particular column attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting it without the explicit null statements, letting PG handle them as needed:

```
insert into regiony (
  m_creation_timestamp,
  m_creation_user,
  m_modification_timestamp,
  m_modification_user,
  kod_regionu,
  nazwa_gminy,
  kod_teryt
  )
select distinct now(),
  'abc',
  now(),
  'abc',
  region_poch,
  export_gmina,
  replace(teryt, '|', '')
from source_table
```